# DNS redirect to AWS S3 static website works with curl, but fails with browser

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, redirect, dns

I own the `covaxx.dev` domain, but it is registered with NameCheap, not with AWS Route53.

I followed the basic [guide to create a "static website" in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), and this works just fine, [index.html](http://covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/) is served as expected, with the bucket named `covaxx.dev` (as it is supposed to).

On NameCheap, I have configured the DNS rule to enable URL Redirect, as described [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain/) using both the `@` and `www` `Host` fields, with a type of `URL Redirect Record` and the `Value` the bucket's URL: `http://covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/`.

This pays off when I try to access the site using `curl` (or `httpie` for that matter):

```
curl -L www.covaxx.dev   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find Vaccine</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Find Vaccine</h1>

<p>This script checks CVS.com for appointment locations near you with available vaccine doses:
it uses the Google Map API to find those which are within a given distance
from the user's chosen location.</p>

<h6>Copyright &copy; 2021 AlertAvert.com  All rights reserved.</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

from the full trace[0] I can see the redirects point to the right place (both for `www.covaxx.dev` and `covaxx.dev`) - so far, so good.

However, when I tried to load the page in a browser (both Firefox, Linux and MacOS; and Safari, MacOS, iOS) they keep spinning and then time out with a "service timed out" error.

I'll be honest, this does not make any sense to me, and I suspect it may be something to do with my hyper-paranoid browser settings, but I'm not sure why is it happening at all.
(I even disabled my VPN, in case it had an impact, but no change).

Any help in untangling the mystery would be mightily appreciated, thanks in advance!

[0] Full trace:

```
$ curl -v -L www.covaxx.dev
*   Trying 192.64.119.50:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.covaxx.dev (192.64.119.50) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.covaxx.dev
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 00:12:07 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 76
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
< X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.covaxx.dev left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
*   Trying 52.218.234.242:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.218.234.242) port 80 (#1)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: s6Hcwjf1E0Prv4QLJTGh9EaTZn5K1YTJy3FmQEtk598OIMyDv/wDeWFR/gzhgn1wgYAN5a/Y2bk=
< x-amz-request-id: 57BM0MN4P842GRFP
< Date: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 00:12:09 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 00:12:03 GMT
< ETag: "8853123d304bc0f26bbe8af3e7a1f71a"
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 429
< Server: AmazonS3
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find Vaccine</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Find Vaccine</h1>

<p>This script checks CVS.com for appointment locations near you with available vaccine doses:
it uses the Google Map API to find those which are within a given distance
from the user's chosen location.</p>

<h6>Copyright &copy; 2021 AlertAvert.com  All rights reserved.</h6>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #1 to host covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Comment: Even if your domain name is not registered with Route53, you could host it in Route53, just change the Namecheap DNS servers to AWS DNS Servers, then create a zone for that domain, it's better to use CloudFront with your S3 hosted website then redirect to your domain name to the CloudFront distribution

Comment: How long ago did you set up the redirect? In your browser, enable debug (F12). Reload the page and watch the network trace. What activity and problems do you see? Flush the local DNS cache `ipconfig /flushdns` (windows) or similar for Linux. Use Internet tools such as mxtoolbox.com to validate your DNS settings.

Answer (score 3):

Mystery solved, posting here in case anyone encounters the same issue.

The root cause is HSTS, a (relatively) new protocol that tells the browser to only use https with a certain domain - this wouldn’t normally matter, because we use http across the redirects (for now, anyway) and it *should have* worked just fine.

Alas, I was using `URL Redirect` with NameCheap, so the request was going to them, and probably there in the redirect maze, at some point the browser got told to switch to https.
This setting is “sticky” in a browser, it gets cached (I’m told) for months, even.

Then, the AWS quirk is that, if you want to redirect a sub domain (e.g. `www`) you need to create an “redirect bucket”, empty, named *exactly* as the sub domain (`www`) and configured (in the Properties tab) to redirect to the original “domain bucket” (which, again, *must* be named exactly as the domain `covaxx.dev`).

Unfortunately, when setting up the bucket redirect, I misunderstood the instructions in the guide and instead of the `covaxx.dev.s3-website-etc.` I set it to `s3://covaxx.dev`.

So there were two errors, which confused the browser, but, amazingly, not `curl` (or `httpie`) and `dig` was happily resolving the domains.

To fix this I had to take two steps:

1. obviously, fix the bucket redirect, pointing the `www` bucket to serve from `covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`;
2. changed my DNS configuration at NameCheap to use a `CNAME` record, redirecting `covaxx.dev` to `covaxx.dev.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

Lo and behold, navigating to `http://www.covaxx.dev` now works (if you haven’t tried it before from your browser).

Comment: HSTS is about 10 years old. Google mandates that `.dev` domains use HTTPS only.

Comment: Hence my "relatively" - in Internet (DNS/IP/HTTP) terms, a youngster :) and, contrary to what most, and Google themselves, think, they are not (yet) King of the Universe and Sole Ruler of the Internet, so `http://www.covaxx.dev` works just fine.

Comment: I  just went through the same excercise except using Google Domains. The simple, one-page index.html they provided in the guide was all I was trying to use... It loaded via the s3 bucket internal URL but wouldn't work through the public facing domain name.

Adding my own details to help others.

For me, I was able to retrieve the page fine using curl and also with lynx on my windwos WSL platform (which ironically is probably older than the protocol you listed above!!) but it did NOT work using Chrome OR Firefox on windows.